# Генерация случайного дробного числа в диапaзоне

Tags: javascript

Не могу найти решение задачи - нужно сгенерировать случайное число именно дробного от 0,0001 до 0,001

Пробовал вот:

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var randFloat = getRandom(0.0001, 0.001);
alert(randFloat);
```

не работает, выдает постоянно 0.0001. Хотя с целыми числами работает без проблем.

Comment: А вы знаете для чего используется `Math.floor`?

Comment: @Regent, Нет незнаю. А этот Ваш вопрос и есть ответ на мой вопрос? Я благодарен Вам, что Вы обратили внимание на мой вопрос, но я не вижу смысла спрашивать о том знаю ли я что то или нет если мой вопрос подразумевает то что я ничего не знаю...

Comment: Ну ничего не знать вы не можете - что-то да вы знаете. Если вы откуда-то взяли сей код, то, на мой взгляд, было бы логично первым же делом поискать в интернете как работают использованные в нём функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На случай если кому то понадобится подобное решение:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

$i = 0;
while($i==0){

    var randIntFee = getRandomInt(10, 100);
    if(randIntFee==20 || randIntFee==30 || randIntFee==40 || randIntFee==50 || randIntFee==60 || randIntFee==70 || randIntFee==80 || randIntFee==90){
        continue;
    }else{
        var randFee = randIntFee/10000;
        $i++;
    }

}
alert(randFee);
```

В данном решении генерируются лишь числа от 0.0001 до 0.001 включительно

Comment: Надеюсь, что, "если кому-то понадобится", у этого человека достанет здравого смысла воспользоваться фрагментом кода из моего ответа. А также не проверять кратность десяти таким способом :).

Answer (score 7):

> Хотя с целыми числами работает без проблем.

Сгенерируйте случайное целое число от `1` до `10` и разделите на `10000`.

Возможны варианты:

- целое число от `10` до `100`, разделить на `100000`;
- целое число от `100` до `1000`, разделить на `1000000`;
- ...

*(у меня еще много хороших идей)*

---

Пошутили, и хватит.

```js
function getRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

setInterval(function(){ console.log(getRandom(0.0001, 0.001)); }, 1000)
```

Comment: Причем каждая следующая хорошая идея будет давать всё больший пул результирующих чисел)

Comment: @Regent Главное свойство моих идей - они улучшаются по нарастающей.

Comment: Ну это всем известно